# Medick or burclover is a "multiple harvest" (?) plant: word for a hay plant with several yields per season

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, translation

What is the most proper adjective or adjectival construction to describe a plant like medick (burclover) that can be harvested for hay several times per season?

> Medick is noted for being a perennial, ____ plant with a high yield.

Would "multiple-harvest" fit, or is it better to remodel the sentence? How about "multi-cut"?

A woman was translating the sentence from Russian, and asked for the proper term on a translators' forum. The original Russian adjective (многоукосный) was unknown even to me, it is so rare, but I wondered whether there is an alternative in English.

This original word is basically "multi-cut" (mnogo = many, kosit' = to cut (grass)).

Comment: I think they're known as **repeat-bearing** or **everbearing**.

Comment: @TRomano - but could "repeat-bearing" apply to a grass which ungergoes its first cut for hay before actually flowering?

Comment: With this consideration in mind, the gal from the translators' forum has chosen "muti-cut".

Comment: What does bur clover produce for human beings to harvest? Multi-cut doesn't make sense. What does it cut? Who cuts it?

Comment: @Rathony - why, hay. I guess guys with scythes cut it.

Comment: @CowperKettle Whoever suggested "multi-cut" doesn't know what they are talking about and their understanding of how English words (especially compound words) work is horrible.

Comment: @Rathony - the client will be able to understand the meaning, I guess, and who is perfect? Let the perfect translator cast the first stone.

Comment: How could a client understand the meaning when he gives someone a job to translate what he doesn't understand? Multi-cut plant? Really?

Comment: If harvested before bearing, then multi-harvest, your original, would be more apt.

Comment: Given that several English speakers (including myself) are not sure which specific word conveys the precise meaning you need, it might be necessary to describe this aspect of the plant rather than use a single word.  I doubt that a reader will analyze it as closely as we are, and even farming-specific words appear to not have narrow enough definitions to suffice.

Comment: _Multicut_ is used in industry. For example https://books.google.com/books?id=B1Dmonequ9oC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=multicut+crop&source=bl&ots=zkqqBpJ-Jl&sig=Va241cq0Uv1-dc0w6jJGdxVY_MI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZyKDWreTMAhVI7oMKHXesCxoQ6AEIJDAD#v=onepage&q=multicut%20crop&f=false & https://books.google.com/books?id=daf832_5u9sC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=multicut+crop&source=bl&ots=_TuwWwUOiO&sig=f_VepuAzC7kCMFwOjz35N-r9iBM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZyKDWreTMAhVI7oMKHXesCxoQ6AEIKjAF#v=onepage&q=multicut%20crop&f=false

Comment: The terms **multi-harvest** and **multiple-harvest** are used in cannabis growing: the species that this work with are apparently everbearing.  For rice an hay, you talk about the number of crops per year, but you can't use the term **multi-crop** because this relates to mixing different species in the same plot.

Comment: @Rathony did you see the links from Adam's comment? Multicut is not completely ridiculous. If there is one thing we should all understand about how English works, it's that there are very few "rules" that don't have at least one exception :) Multicut crop seems completely reasonable to me, so I don't understand why you think it doesn't make sense. Would you explain?

Comment: @ColleenV "Cut" vs "Harvest", "Plant" vs "Crop".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Multicut** is a good choice.

This can sound a little strange, if you aren't familiar with the agricultural uses of the word *cut*, which extend beyond the idea of slicing, and directly into the concept of harvest.  For farmers, "*cut*" can be noun synonymous with *harvest.*  Example:

> Single-cut [clover] does not flower in the seeding year, or after the first **cut** in succeeding years.
>   <sub>http://www.omafra.gov.on.ca/english/crops/facts/info_redclover_haylage.htm</sub>

A farmer's *first cut* is the first harvest of hay in a given year.

Adjectives are commonly formed with an ordinal number and *cut.* (e.g. [*first cut clover*](https://www.google.com/#q=%22first+cut%22+clover), *[second cut alfalfa](https://www.google.com/#q=%22second+cut%22+alfalfa)*, *[third cut timothy](https://www.google.com/#q=third+cut+timothy)*)

Timothy, alfalfa, and clover are all crops that are at least *[double-cut crops](https://www.google.com/#q=double-cut+crops)*.

You can refer to any double or triple-cut crops as [multicut crops](https://www.google.com/#q=%22multicut+crop%22).  For example:

> Improved, **multicut** oats are very popular in urban irrigated areas, and have almost replaced poor quality wheat and rice straw as the basis of winter feed.
>    <sub>Source: [*The United Nations*](http://www.fao.org/docrep/008/y5765e/y5765e0a.htm)</sub>

Or

> In Pakistan a little information is available on the interactive effects of nitrogen and sowing methods on the quality and fodder yield of **multicut** sorghum.
>   <sub>Source: [PERFORMANCE OF MULTICUT FORAGE SORGHUM UNDER VARIOUS SOWING
>   METHODS AND NITROGEN APPLICATION RATES](http://www.thejaps.org.pk/docs/v-23-1/35.pdf)</sub>

Most of these terms are not in general parlance - but then again, many city dwellers don't know the difference between hay and straw, and have no idea that multiple cuts are possible.  If the translation is being done for people in or familiar with the agriculture industry, **multicut** would be the expected term.

The change I *would* recommend to that translator is the choice of the word "plant."  In agriculture, plants that can be harvested are usually referred to as "crops" when they are being discussed as categories - the individual organism is a plant, the category of organism is a crop.

> Medick is noted for being a perennial, **multicut crop** with a high yield.

---

As discussed in the comments to the original post, related words include:

*Everbearing:* providing fruit more or less continuously through an extended season, like some berries in my region.

*Repeat bearing:*  developing ripe fruit more than once in a season, like some fig trees.